# "Do you know of any" usage

Tags: grammar, idioms

"Do you know of any English coaching centers nearby?"
Is that sentence correct?

I added "any" unintentionally while I was talking, and I wonder if that is grammatically right.

"Do you know any English coaching centers near by?" is perhaps the right one. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

*Know* means you have direct knowledge about something while *know of* is indirect.

Consider your example.

> Do you know of any English coaching centers nearby?

can be interpreted as: have you heard of any English coaching centers nearby? (you may not have been to any of them)

> Do you know any English coaching centers nearby?

can be interpreted as: have you ever been to any of the English coaching centers nearby? (you must have been to one of those centers and was once involved in their activities)

In summary, I would say the former is asking if I'm aware of the existence of any centers while the latter is asking if I have had experiences with any of the centers (and if I'm able to make recommendations).

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are equally correct and mean the same thing. *Nearby* is one word, though.

Answer (score 0):

"Know of any" is correct; you probably heard it before and picked it up.

"Know of" is better than "know" here, because to "know of" is to be aware of the existence of something, which is what you are asking: do there exist any coaching centers in the area.

Contrast:

> ? Do you know of any good dentists in the area?

This is somewhat questionable. You cannot know whether a dentist is good or not simply by being aware of their existence.  So this is essentially asking: *have you heard from other people that there are good dentists in the area, and do you remember who those dentists are?*

If someone tells you that he has been to a good dentist and gives you the contact info, you thereby know **of** a good dentist. But you do not know that dentist.

> Do you know of any dentists in this area?

= Do you know whether there exist dentists in this area and where? (Have you seen a dentist's business signage on a building somewhere around here?)

> Do you know any dentist in this area?

= Are you familiar with a dentist in this area? (Is there a dentist here you have visited?)